# Adding an interpreter to RubyMine

Tags: ruby, rubymine

I recently downloaded RubyMine 7.1. This is my first time using Ruby. I am trying to add an interpreter to my first project. When I go to Settings -> Languages and Frameworks -> Ruby SDK and Gems, and I try to add an interpreter path, it says "The selected file is not a valid home for Ruby SDK." What does this mean and how can I add an SDK?

Comment: Their help docs do a good job showing how to do this:

https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/help/configuring-ruby-sdk.html#d724185e110

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using a Ruby SDK version that is not supported by the RubyMine.

Try downgrading Ruby, and configuring IDE again.